# <li> elements have some mysterious left padding added on iphone over 3G but not over wifi

Tags: iphone, css

I'm having some strange issues on `<li>` elements when viewing my webpage on an iphone.

There appears to be a mysterious padding added to the left of ALL `<li>` elements on the page (almost like a `padding-left:30px`) when viewing the webpage over 3G/Edge/GPRS. However, when viewing the page over wifi, the padding disappears, and the page renders as expected.

I use Eric Meyers reset.css stylesheet to reset my styles. This issue has happened to me on previous sites I've built so I know it's not localised just to this particular site. Perhaps O2 (my network provider) are modifying the css before sending it over to my iphone?

If you want to try and replicate this for yourself, my site is at http://www.pyre7.com

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: No problem on my iPhone, both on 3G and wifi. My provider is T-Mobile (dutch)

Comment: The plot thickens - I'm starting to think O2 is modifying my CSS before sending it to the iphone. I know they already do this for images before transmission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found this article. It appears o2's proxy cache is in fact modifying content.

http://startupcafe.co.uk/2010/07/23/o2-compression-on-mobile-devices/

Answer (score -1):

It could have something to do with slow speed of 3G and how you render CSS

Comment: No, it's nothing to do with the "slow" speed of the 3G or how I render CSS. If you hover over the li element on the iphone, you can see safari selects the entire li element and there is clearly some CSS related padding there.